Calculate accuracy in libtorch (C++) when using Softmax
The below code is able to learn the generic pattern and it is able to predict as expected:
torch::manual_seed(42);

torch::nn::Sequential net(
        torch::nn::Linear(300, 301),
        torch::nn::ReLU(),
        torch::nn::Linear(301, 6),
        torch::nn::ReLU(),
        torch::nn::Linear(6, 2)
    );

torch::nn::CrossEntropyLoss loss_fn;
torch::optim::Adam optimizer(net->parameters(), torch::optim::AdamOptions(0.001));

torch::Tensor inputs = torch::randn( { 5, 300 });

torch::Tensor outputs = torch::zeros( { 5, 2 });
outputs[0][0] = 0; outputs[0][1] = 1;
outputs[1][0] = 1; outputs[1][1] = 0;
outputs[2][0] = 0; outputs[2][1] = 1;
outputs[3][0] = 1; outputs[3][1] = 0;
outputs[4][0] = 0; outputs[4][1] = 1;

torch::Tensor targets = outputs.argmax(1);

size_t num_epochs = 100;

for (size_t epoch = 0; epoch < num_epochs; ++epoch)
{
    optimizer.zero_grad();
    torch::Tensor outputs = net->forward(inputs);
    torch::Tensor loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets);
    loss.backward();
    optimizer.step();
    std::cout << "Epoch [" << epoch + 1 << "], Loss: " << loss.item<double>() << std::endl;
}

net->eval();  // Set the model to evaluation mode

torch::Tensor final_outputs = net->forward(inputs);
torch::Tensor final_predicted = final_outputs.argmax(1);
torch::Tensor final_correct = final_predicted.eq(targets);
double final_accuracy = final_correct.sum().item<double>() / targets.size(0);
std::cout << "Final Accuracy: " << final_accuracy * 100 << "%" << std::endl << std::endl;

// Prediction phase
torch::Tensor test_outputs = net->forward(inputs);
torch::Tensor test_probabilities = torch::softmax(test_outputs, 1);

std::cout << "Outputs Original : " << std::endl << outputs << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << "Outputs Predicted: " << std::endl << test_probabilities << std::endl << std::endl;

Output:
Final Accuracy: 100%

Outputs Original : 
 0  1
 1  0
 0  1
 1  0
 0  1
[ CPUFloatType{5,2} ]

Outputs Predicted: 
 0.0002  0.9998
 0.9999  0.0001
 0.0001  0.9999
 0.9998  0.0002
 0.0001  0.9999
[ CPUFloatType{5,2} ]

A lot of examples in internet suggest the code above. It seems its working as expected, but I am not sure why is the final accuracy logic "working"? As I understand CrossEntropyLoss already implements LogSoftmax, so I did not add this function at the end of the Sequential components (layers).
If I perform forward to predict (loss function not required to predict) also I have to perform Softmax manually to have  the implicit behavior that I had in the training process given by CrossEntropyLoss. But mostly of the examples in internet dont include the usage of Softmax or LogSoftmax to calculate the accuracy.
I know argmax(1) gets the index of the highest value in the output Tensor, but still that Tensor was not affected by Softmax
The question is, should I include Softmax or LogSoftmax in the code that I am using to get the final accuracy? or the nature of the output given by forward is already able to provide quality in terms of accuracy? Ex:
torch::Tensor final_outputs = torch::softmax(net->forward(inputs), 1);
Note 1: Both of the cases give me 100% accuracy, but I think I should add Softmax. What I dont understand is: I saw many examples and none of them use it.
Note 2: Some examples add log_softmax at the end of the Sequential net, and use nll_loss as Loss function, which does not include Softmax. But this does not answer the main question.

This is not a programming question, it is about the practice of machine learning. As such, it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You may try posting at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, but be sure to read their rules before posting.

As a side note, you should ask yourself whether the omission of softmax ever produces the wrong accuracy value. If it doesn't, then it is a perfectly valid algorithm (hint: it is).
